# Beautiful soup ignore inner html

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following html ,where i want to get the product name only and ignore the rest of the html.How can i do this

I want this as the oputpout using beautifulsoup `Apple iPhone 4 Verizon`

```
  <h1 itemprop="itemreviewed">Apple iPhone 4 Verizon    
                        <div class="right">
  <span class="s_button_follow_special" style="display: block">
  <a href="javascript:;" style="display: block" onclick="subscribe(this, 1, 5132);" class="follow_1_5132 s_button_2 s_button_follow" title="Follow Apple iPhone 4 Verizon"><em class="s_icon s_icon_follow"></em>Follow</a>
  <a class="s_button_2 s_button_follow_arrow" href="javascript:;" onclick="subscribe(this, 1, 5132, '', 2);"></a>
  </span>
  <a href="javascript:;" style="display: none" onclick="subscribe(this, 1, 5132);" class="unfollow_1_5132 s_button_2 s_button_follow_disabled s_button_following" title="Unfollow Apple iPhone 4 Verizon"><span><em class="s_icon s_icon_following"></em>Following</span></a>
  </div>
  </h1>


  header= soup('h1', {'itemprop' : 'itemreviewed'})
```

Comment: i have given at the end of the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Apple iPhone 4 Verizon` text is its own element in the parse tree, separate from any other; you can select it by fetching a nearby element and navigating with `nextSibling`, `previousSibling`, `next` or `previous`.

So this should work:

```
header = soup.find('h1', itemprop='itemreviewed')
text = header.next
```

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(<h1 ....)
header = soup.h1['itemprop'].contents
```

Comment: I think `.contents` will fetch all of the contents of the tag, including all of the html such as the div etc.  You could try `.contents[0]` though, to get the first element only.